# lightning datatable: get additional records by enableInfiniteLoading

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable, lightning-components

How can I get additional records by lightning datatable enableInfiniteLoading?
I wanna get more 10 records when scroll lightning datatable,
but the datatable shows only first 10 records when scroll down.(can get same 10 records)

How can I improve my code?

## component

```
<lightning:datatable keyField="id"
                     data="{!v.data}"
                     columns="{!v.columns}"
                     enableInfiniteLoading="true"
                     onloadmore="{!c.loadMoreData}"/>
```

## controller.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.columns", [
            {label:"product code",fieldName:"Name", type:"text"}
},
loadMoreData: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", true);
        component.set("v.loadMoreStatus", "Loading");
        helper.getMoreData(component, event, component.get("v.data").length);
}
})
```

## helper.js

```
({
    getMoreData : function(component, event, offSetCount){
        var getRecords = component.get("c.getRecords");
        getRecords.setParams({
            "Limits":component.get("v.limit"),
            "intOffSet":offSetCount
        });
        console.log(component.get("v.limit"));
        console.log(offSetCount);
        getRecords.setCallback(this, function(response){
            component.set("v.data",response.getReturnValue());
            event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", false);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(getRecords);
    }
})
```

## Apex

```
public class lookUpSearch {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<EMITEM__c> getRecords(Integer Limits, Integer intOffSet) {
        System.debug(Integer.valueOf(Limits));
        System.debug(Integer.valueOf(Limits));
        return [SELECT Name
                FROM EMITEM__c
                ORDER BY Name ASC
                LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(Limits)
                OFFSET :Integer.valueOf(intOffSet)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i found in your code,you binding the fresh data only by replacing existing data, it shouldn't, you should concat the fresh data in to existing data. [Infiniterowloading](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example)

helper.js

```
({
getMoreData : function(component, event, offSetCount){

    var getRecords = component.get("c.getRecords");

    getRecords.setParams({
        "Limits":component.get("v.limit"),
        "intOffSet":offSetCount
    });
    console.log(component.get("v.limit"));
    console.log(offSetCount);
    getRecords.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var currentData = component.get("v.data"),
            newData = currentData.concat(response.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.data",newData);
        event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", false);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getRecords);
}
})
```